# How can I find two numbers, $a$ and $b$, from this logarithmic equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I want to find two positive numbers $a$, $b$ from the equation:
$$\log _{2 a+2 b+1}\left(4
   a^2+b^2+1\right)+\log _{4 a
   b+1}(2 a+2 b+1)=2.$$
I tried

```
Reduce[{Log[2 a + 2 b + 1, 4 a^2 + b^2 + 1] + 
     Log[4 a b + 1, 2 a + 2 b + 1] == 2 && a > 0 && b > 0}, {a, 
  b }, Reals]
```

I couldn't get the result. How can I find?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plotting with limited plot range shows where it possibly happens.

```
Plot3D[Log[2 a + 2 b + 1, 4 a^2 + b^2 + 1] + Log[4 a b + 1, 2 a + 2 b + 1],
    {a, 0, 5}, {b, 0, 6}, PlotRange -> {All, All, {1.9, 2.1}}]
```

[image]

Which looks like `1/2 < a < 1` and `1 < b < 2` but it's not obvious whether the minimum reaches `2`, so ask `NMinimize`

```
NMinimize[{Log[2 a + 2 b + 1, 4 a^2 + b^2 + 1] + Log[4 a b + 1, 2 a + 2 b + 1],
     1/2 < a < 1, 1 < b < 2}, {a, b}]
```

> ```
> {2., {a -> 0.75, b -> 1.5}}
> ```

Exact test:

```
Log[2 a + 2 b + 1, 4 a^2 + b^2 + 1] + Log[4 a b + 1, 2 a + 2 b + 1] /. {a -> 3/4, b -> 3/2}
```

> 2

Answer (score 4):

You can use FindMinimum:

```
FindMinimum[(Log[2 a + 2 b + 1, 4 a^2 + b^2 + 1] + 
    Log[4 a b + 1, 2 a + 2 b + 1] - 2)^2, {{a, 1}, {b, 1}}]

{1.2326*10^-30, {a -> 0.75, b -> 1.5}}
```